# How can I save a web page in Redis cache for improving speed of website?

Tags: html, caching, web, redis, save

Is there any way to save the web page HTML in redis cache for further use and improving the speed performance.

Comment: did you find any solution for it

Answer (score 2):

I can provide basic snapshot how can you store page content into redis and retrieve it from redis.

```
$redis_key= md5("<full_url_of_webiste or $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]>");
$output = $redis->get($redis_key);
if(empty($output ))
{
    ob_start();
    /*
    Your all code here for page 
    */
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();
    $output = $redis->set($redis_key,$output);
}
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using redis to cache almost each and every static page used to server google for SEO.

Answer is **Redis Strings**

The Redis String type is the simplest type of value you can associate with a Redis key. It is the only data type in Memcached, so it is also very natural for newcomers to use it in Redis.

Since Redis keys are strings, when we use the string type as a value too, we are mapping a string to another string. The string data type is useful for a number of use cases, like caching HTML fragments or pages.

Checkout the below link :- http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro

Comment: Hey Nishant, Thankyou so much for your guidence, but is there any way to save the common  header and footer css or js scripts in redis cache. So we do not need to load these files further..

Comment: @astha :- you can save any thing seperately in redis, using key value pair, you can put seperate keys for header and footer, and store the html respectively.

Comment: @Nishant can we cache pages with dynamic data (data coming from api calls) ?